# Install Blender (.tar.bz2) in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: software-installation, blender

How can I install `Blender 2.78a` ? 
The file extension is `.tar.bz2` .
 I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55796/how-can-i-install-a-tar-bz2-file) but as `10.04` is much older and I am installing a different file I felt that I need to learn specific instruction for installing `blender` .

Answer (score 6):

To get version 2.8 from terminal:

Add repository, update and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install blender
```

To revert to the official version:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to settle for a little bit older version of Blender, Blender 2.76.b can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 and Blender 2.79 in Ubuntu 18.04. Blender 2.78 snap package can be installed from the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 and later as follows.

```
sudo snap install blender --classic
```

After you logout and then login again, you can launch Blender 2.78 from the Dash like any other graphical application.

To update the blender snap package after it is installed run this command:

```
sudo snap refresh blender
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.tar.bz2` files that you can download from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/) are a compressed tarball of the compiled version of blender. You should be able to unzip the file and run blender from within the unzipped folder.

If you don't want to [compile the newest version of blender yourself](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake), then the other option as described by George is to use a third party repository that has a newer build of blender.

Also of note is that you can install the current version of blender through [steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make new entries in the applicatinos folder : **/usr/share/applications**

This is an example and you only need to change the path to the Blender binary and save it as a *.desktop* file such as example.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender 2.7b
GenericName=3D modeler
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Keywords=3d;cg;modeling;animation;painting;sculpting;texturing;video editing;video tracking;rendering;render engine;cycles;game engine;python;
Exec=~/path/to/blender.tar %f
Icon=blender
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```